# Distributable ASP.NET web server for a commercial product

Tags: .net, asp.net, hosting

Does anybody know of a commercially supported distributable web server that can host ASP.NET applications?

I have a commercial server based application to which I want to add a web interface (sort of like a portal for clients.) I cannot expect that all of my customers will have, or want to run, IIS.

Cassini seems a bit limited without SSL support and if someone can provide information on where to find the cassini source code and if its licensed to use for a commercial product, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet might be to host it yourself (in the same way Cassini does).  Check out the [System.Web.Hosting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.aspx) APIs ... which do support SSL according to this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/adarshk/archive/2004/11/10/255467.aspx).

The actually amount of code required is fairly small.

I've done something similar with an unmanaged server hosting the CLR and ASP.NET and it provides for very easy interop using C++/CLI between managed world and the unmanaged.

Comment: I was really hoping I would find a small ISV with a ready solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe UltiDev Cassini is what you are looking for:
http://www.ultidev.com/products/Cassini/

Edit: Cassini sources can be found here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2005/09/27/474534.aspx

Comment: UtilDev is based on cassini and does not include SSL support. Licensing is also a mystery.

Comment: For your information: the cassini source includes an eula (eula.rtf) - text here: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/109466/. Type is "Shared Source License for ASP.NET Source Projects"

Answer (score 0):

You could always look at [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) + [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Comment: Would that mean the the client will need to install Apache + Mono or is there a way to load ASP.NET into Apache?

Comment: Mono is a plug-in to Apache that hosts the ASP.Net runtime environment.  The client would need to be running Apache, on whatever OS they wanted, and have the Mono plug-in installed.  If you were to go this route you would want to test thoroughly, but I've never had much trouble with Mono.

Comment: Sounds doable but installing apache+mone just to run a add-on is a lot to ask from clients. (and I doubt their is commercial support available for such a setup)